# Bypassing NoneType in a list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension, nonetype

To work around when there is no value `x.competition.name`, I tried to use `is not None`:

```
'competition': [x.competition.name if x.competition.name is not None else '-' for x in a]
```

But the error still keeps showing up:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
```

How can I go about getting around this problem?

Comment: depending on the nature of the data structure you could also use `hasattr(x.competition, 'name')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to test `x.competition`:

`'competition': [x.competition.name if x.competition is not None else '-' for x in a]`

Answer (score 2):

Apparently competition is None, so please replace

```
[x.competition.name if x.competition.name is not None else '-' for x in a]
```

using

```
[x.competition.name if x.competition is not None else '-' for x in a]
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message is saying that you tried to get `None.name`. That means `x.competition` must be `None`, which is why you can't get a `name` attribute from it. Instead, try making your condition `x.competition is not None`.